# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: swift, urlsession

I am getting this error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context, while I am trying to perform a URLRequest:

```
func performRequest(_ request: URLRequest){
    // Enviar la solicitud a la API de OpenAI
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        // Procesar la respuesta de la API de OpenAI
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        if let safeData = data {
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseOpenIA.self, from: safeData)
                if let safeResponse = response.data.Choice.message {
                    responseMessage = safeResponse
                    print(responseMessage)
                } else {
                    // La respuesta no contiene ninguna URL de imagen
                    print("La respuesta no contiene ninguna URL de imagen")
                }
            } catch {
                // Error al decodificar la respuesta JSON
                print("Error al decodificar la respuesta JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } else {
            // No se recibió ninguna respuesta del servidor
            print("No se recibió ninguna respuesta del servidor")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I didn't find any solution on Google. It is a SwiftUI project.

It is weird because the same code works for me in another Swift Storyboard project.

Does anyone know what could be the error?
Thank you

Comment: You likely have a different return type later and the compiler can’t infer the type of Task.

Comment: I updated the question, could you help me to find the bug? I don't figure out where is it

Comment: Unrelated but the error `print("No se recibió ninguna respuesta del servidor")` will **never** be reached. If there is no `error` then `data` has always a value. And (also) never print `error.localizedDescription` in a Codable context. Just print the `error`.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: What you've included is not enough to reproduce the error. Please include a [mre]

Comment: The “Type of expression is ambiguous without more context” error means that code is sufficiently complex that it was unable to infer a type. Unfortunately, this error is often a false positive, a result of some other error in our code. E.g., a misplaced bracket here or there can result in these sorts of cryptic errors. (If I suspect a missing bracket, I select all my code and press ctrl-i to re-indent it, and it brings any misplaced brackets into stark relief.) But your bug likely does not rest in the above code (though, if you're interested, we could make unrelated observations).